# Отключить equalheight.js на разрешении экрана меньше n-го

Tags: javascript

В теме собственно весь вопрос. Нужно чтоб скрипт работал только на больших экранах, на маленьких не работал.

Comment: почитайте документацию: https://github.com/jorenvanhee/EqualHeight.js. Пишут что этот плагин уже DEPRECATED и рекомендую к использованию другой. Так вот этого другого плагина есть вот такой вызов функционала: `$('.item').matchHeight({ property: 'min-height' });`. Я так понимаю это то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте внимательно документацию к плагину: https://github.com/jorenvanhee/EqualHeight.js

В ней есть [ссылка на пример](https://github.com/JorenVanHee/EqualHeight.js/blob/master/demo/advanced.html) и в этом примере есть такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var equalHeight = $('.Grid--demo p').equalHeight({wait: true});
    // Browser supports matchMedia
    if (window.matchMedia) {
        // MediaQueryList
        var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
        // MediaQueryListListener
        var equalHeightCheck = function (mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                equalHeight.start();
            } else {
                equalHeight.stop();
            }
        };
        // Add listener
        mql.addListener(equalHeightCheck);
        // Manually call listener
        equalHeightCheck(mql);
    }
    // Browser doesn't support matchMedia
    else {
        equalHeight.start();

    }
});
```

Это случаем не то, что вам нужно?

А ещё пишут что этот плагин уже DEPRECATED и рекомендуют к использованию другой: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height.

И у этого другого плагина есть нужный вам функционал:

`$('.item').matchHeight({ property: 'min-height' });`

В общем, выбирайте, лично я бы задумался, когда увидел бы что плагин, который я использую deprecated.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите скрипт из файла в функцию и запускайте вот так:

```
function equalheight() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {           /* при ширине экрана больше 1200 пикселей */
    document.querySelector('header').style.display = 'none';    /* скрыть блок <header> */
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", adaptHeader);       /* запускать при загрузке окна*/
window.addEventListener("resize", adaptHeader);     /* запускать при ресайзе окна*/
```

Comment: Можете подробнее написать?

Comment: @АлександрСуетин дополнил код примером и комментариями

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо большое! Написал вот так:

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {
    $('.eh').equalHeights()
}
```